# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Using nedb database, no recursion

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, nedb

I am using nedb as a database for a small discord bot I have created.
Downloaded via `npm install nedb --save`, and set up in the main file with:

```
const { callbackify } = require('util');
var db = new Datastore('botDB.db');
db.loadDatabase();
```

Additionally, I am using these search functions to implement an initial list within the database and search for people within the database.

```
function findPlayer(params, callback)
{
    db.find({name:params}, (err,docs)=>
    {
        callback(docs);
    });
}

findPlayer('list', function(users){
    if (!users[0])
    {
        let players = {
            name:'list',
            list:[]
        };
        db.insert(players,function(err,newDoc){});
    }
})
```

Finally, I create a command to add someone to the database. With the following code being placed as a callback within a findPlayer function.

```
let updateData = {
                        name:key,
                        display:args[0],
                        socialCredit: 0,
                        games: []
                    }
                    db.insert(updateData,function(err,newDoc){
                        message.reply("Added you to the database.")
                        console.log(err)
                    });

                    findInList(key, function(users){
                        if(!users[0])
                        {
                            db.update({name:'list'},{$push:{list:key}},{},function(){});
                        }
                    })
```

When i run the code, and type the command, the console logs this error.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.isArray (<anonymous>)
    at deepCopy (C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Editing\Coding Projects\Discod Bot\node_modules\nedb\lib\model.js:120:12)
    at C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Editing\Coding Projects\Discod Bot\node_modules\nedb\lib\model.js:130:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepCopy (C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Editing\Coding Projects\Discod Bot\node_modules\nedb\lib\model.js:128:22)
    at C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Editing\Coding Projects\Discod Bot\node_modules\nedb\lib\model.js:130:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepCopy (C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Editing\Coding Projects\Discod Bot\node_modules\nedb\lib\model.js:128:22)
    at C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Editing\Coding Projects\Discod Bot\node_modules\nedb\lib\model.js:130:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

When researching this error, most results i have come accross have been using recursion of some form, and that the stack size is 1000 or something rediculous when i am implementing 1 object into an almost completely empty database. I have another command that is very similar that implements into the database correctly, and i cannot find a distinguishing factor between the two functions that would change how it works, they both have the same format.